# Laravel 7 - different public folder or change component path

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I have project in laravel 7 with this folder structure:

```
laravel
 - app
 - boostrap
 - ...
pages
 - login
  - login.blade.php
 - records
 - ...
```

The issue is, that if I create a component in `resources/views/components/input.blade.php`
I get 2 fatal errors (throwable in handler -> I have Throwbale declaration in Handler based on upgrade guide and second error is ReflectionException) and the component does not work. If I use that component in blade, which is located in `resources/views/welcome.blade.php` the component works. 
My question is, how I can use components in the different public folder than default folder? Or how I can change the default resource path of component folder and use it in my folder structure.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Probably because components are purely blade related. You can't use it in any other way. What happens if you call the component directly from a controller, I don't know. But that's not the purpose of a component. It is a helper to keep your code DRY while working with blade templates.

Comment: Well, I used component in blade file, e.g login.blade.php. One difference is, that blade file is not in *resource/view but outside* of the laravel folder.

Comment: Oh. But that won't work. This is not clear in the setup of your question. All views are, by definition, under the `resources/views/` map. Although you can change this map in `config/view.php`, you won't change the fact that ALL your views have to live there. This is logical as Laravel is a VMC framework. It indicates the map where frontend designers can do their thing. It is designed to avoid confusion for non-programmers.

Comment: Dimitri, firstly, thank you for your answers. For the clarification, blade files in pages folder (outside of the laravel folder) are working well without components. Because I have changed the resource path in config/view.php. Imagine pages folder as a folder for my views. Except, that is not in laravel resource/view folder (Reason is that project tech lead wants to this kind of separation). Based on your last answer, I need to move all my blade files into resource/view folder? Is not any method how to change path for components? Thank you.

Comment: As far as I know moving only components to another folder out of the indicated view base path won't work. You can see it in the controller view requests and internal blade links. Everything starts with that exact base path. `welcome` and `components.input` are examples of your description. There is no `../../components.input`. It's how it's created. Explain this to your team members. All in all it's front end anyway. Whatever you do, make sure you don't put blade templates on a public folder. As long as Laravel knows where to find and process your view files, there is no problem.

Comment: Anyway, I moved components into resource/view/components folder and now it is good.